# How to change/edit side panel of Ubuntu standard file manager?

Tags: gnome, filemanager

I have no idea why i can't edit general side panel. I can't delete unnecessary folders. Maybe we had some config idk. Internet don't say anything, or outdated guides.
That critical because they took alot of space and makes it difficult to reach the button with disks.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit these two files to comment out the standard Nautilus bookmarks that you don't want:

```
~/.config/user-dirs.dirs
/etc/xdg/user-dirs.defaults   (requires sudo)
```

Restart Nautilus after editing the first file. Upon login, the first file may be overwritten by the second file, hence the need to edit the second file.

Comment: Yup, that worked